# How to use Substring in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint, ssis

I want to export data from  SharePoint list to SQL using SSIS.
In SharePoint list, i have a column as multi select, So i am getting below value in my column

```
1;#control 1;#3;#control 3
```

I want to use substring in derived column in such a way that i should get below result

```
1,3
```

I want only ID from the given column.

I have tried below code

SUBSTRING(ColumnName,1,FINDSTRING(ColumnName,";#",1) - 1)

But it only gives me answer as

```
1
```

Can anyone please help me out.?

Comment: What are the column names of the list you provided? And which ones do you want returned?

Comment: @NickyvV My Column Name is "Controls"

Comment: how about SUBSTRING(ColumnName,1,FINDSTRING(ColumnName,";#",1) - 1) & "," & SUBSTRING(ColumnName,1,FINDSTRING(ColumnName,";#",3) - 1)

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz i am getting below error
"Error at Data Flow Task [Derived Column [483]]: The data type "DT_WSTR" cannot be used with binary operator "&". The type of one or both of the operands is not supported for the operation. To perform this operation, one or both operands need to be explicitly cast with a cast operator"

Comment: @Prashant Bhojani, is it only for the two values (1,3) or there can be multiple values ?

Comment: @ram_sql there can be single or multiple values.
For example, If there is a single value, then my column value will be 1;#control 1
And if there are multiple values , then it will be 1;#control 1;#3;#control 3

Comment: What version of SSIS you're using?

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko i am using SSIS 2012

Comment: Which 1 and 3 did you extract? Help me understand that data. Number, semicolon, sharp sign, description and number, semicolon, sharp sign number, semicolon, description and number. I **assume** the first number and the second number that is preceded by the # is how you identify the desired entities but why does the first number not have a leading #?

Comment: For what you're doing, unknown number of things, derived column is going to be way more work than you want. My original approach was just  to use a few `REPLACE` calls but that's not going to cover all the bases. Instead, use a Script Component, acting as a transformation and then you'll be able to leverage the .NET string library, possibly a regular expression, which will be much more efficient at solving this

Comment: Also, work with your coworker as you have **both** asked the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684313/how-to-use-substring-in-ssis)

Comment: @PrashantBhojani sorry, wrong operator:  SUBSTRING(ColumnName,1,FINDSTRING(ColumnName,";#",1) - 1) + "," + SUBSTRING(ColumnName,1,FINDSTRING(ColumnName,";#",3) - 1)

Answer (score 2):

Because there is an unknown number of controls selected in your SharePoint Multi-Select, a Derived Column transformation is not going to work for you.  You'll have to use a script.

One way to parse your string is with regular expressions.  You'll have to add an output to the script transformation and assign your parsed string to that output.

```
        Regex controlExpression = new Regex(@"control ([0-9]+)");
        MatchCollection controlMatches = controlExpression.Matches(--YOUR INPUT HERE--);
        String output = string.Join(",", 
            (controlMatches.Cast<Match>().Select(n => n.Groups[1].ToString())).ToArray());
```